# Render a JBuilder view in html view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, jbuilder

I've created a json view with JBuilder. But I want to preload this into a data object, so Backbone has access to the data early on without fetching for it.

How can I render the list.json.jbuilder view into my list.html.erb view?

Normally without jbuilder, I'd do something like this:

```
<div data-list="<%= @contents.to_json %>"></div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`render`, when called from within a view, returns a string rendering of the passed template or partial; you can embed that string into your view as you like. Note though that:

- You have to append your template name with the type suffix/extension. If you don't, Rails may get confused about which template file you're calling; ie: it might choose `list.html.erb` instead of `list.json.jbuilder`. If you're making this call *from* `list.html.erb`, trying to render `list.html.erb` results in infinite recursion and a SystemStackError. Using the `:format` option for `render` doesn't appear to work.
- You have to specify the qualified path to the template; it won't find the right template for "list.json" just because `list.json.jbuilder` resides in the same directory as `list.html.erb`.
- You need to pass the output of the `render` call through `raw`; otherwise, it will get escaped when it gets embedded into the view.

So, for your example, you might write this, assuming your templates were in `/app/views/foo`:

```
<div data-list="<%= raw render(:template => "foo/list.json", :locals => { :contents => @contents }) %>"></div>
```

Comment: This is such a protip!  Thanks.  You can also use `<%== %>` instead of `raw`

Comment: I was challenged to render a html partial as json propery with jbuilder. render does the job here as well json.prop render(:template => 'partials/_resort_summary', :locals => {resort: @resort})

Comment: Thank you very much. I have spent quite some time figuring out how I'd do this.

Comment: Great answer @Craig Walker. I'd like to add that you need to include the word `template` if you want to use a jBuilder file that doesn't start with an underscore. Reading the official Rails Guides one gets the impression that this is optional, but it makes a difference in this situation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render (section 2.2.2). So `<%= raw render template: "foo/list.json.jbuilder" %>` works in Rails 5.2.

Comment: @CraigWalker - It has been some years, but perhaps it's worth asking: is it safe to call `raw` user inputted json? Would it using `h` instead ben an unacceptable proposition?