# How to return empty strings instead of "<null"> in jbuilder as default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

Right now I get:

```
{"id":1,"name":"HerzASS ratiopharm","dosage":null}
```

I would like to return `""` instead of `null`

But as default. How to achieve that. I don't want to add `m.dosage || ""` for each attribute in my application.

I am keeping my jbuilder views in `views/api/documents/_document.json.jbuilder`

```
json.id document.id
json.category document.category # sometimes this is nil
json.note document.note
json.attachments document.attachments do |attachment|
  json.url URI.join(request.url, attachment.url).to_s
end
json.created_at document.created_at
json.updated_at document.updated_at
```

Comment: I don't get and where should I put this method?

Comment: just after you get the json data.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def replace_null(yourhash)
  yourhash.each do |k,v|
    if v == nil then
      yourhash[k] = ""
    end
  end
end
```

or

```
yourhash.each{|k,v| a[k] = "" if v == nil}
```

Comment: Hmm but I am keeping all my jbuilder views in api/views/document.json.jbuilder file.

Comment: You can put ruby code in your view. Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459750/render-a-jbuilder-view-in-html-view